# Storing something other than a string in SuspensionManager.SessionState

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime

The sample apps include a Suspension Manager class that stores session state in a Dictionary, but never attempt to store anything except a string in it.

Whenever I store anything else but a string, then trigger the serialization, I get the following error

Type 'System.RuntimeType' with data contract name 'RuntimeType:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.

Do I have to do something else to be able to store other types in SessionState?

Answer (score 8):

You will need to do two things:

Firstly, ensure the type you are (de)serializing is decorated with the `DataContract` attribute from `System.Runtime.Serialization` and ensure it's members are decorated appropriately. For example in c#:

```cs
[DataContract]
public struct Product
{
     [DataMember]
     public Guid Id { get; set; }

     [DataMember]
     public DateTime ManufactureDate { get; set; }

     [DataMember]
     public decimal Cost { get; set; }  
}
```

Secondly you will need to call SessionManager's `AddKnownType<T>()` (with T being the type you need) before attempting to (de)serialize it.

Comment: For the second step do you mean SuspensionManager.KnownTypes.Add(T)?

Comment: @diadyne Either works I believe. SuspensionManager has a method AddKnownType<T>() which calls KnownTypes.Add(typeof(T))

Answer (score 0):

looking at the SessionManager code it is only string types, guess you will have to 'roll your own'
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/ApplicationData-sample-fb043eb2/sourcecode?fileId=43552&pathId=6033729